# JSON over Diameter protocol

Tags: json, xml, diameter-protocol

I am new to Diameter and have this basic question.

I have 2 peers talking to each other over Diameter protocol. I need to send some data between these 2 entities and I am trying to decide whether JSON or XML is supported over Diameter. What is the best way to transfer file content over Diameter? Is it possible to transfer JSON data over Diameter?

Any sample links or code samples would be helpful.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You can send any kind of data you want with Diameter, but keep in mind that it is designed for transmitting Authentication, Authorization and Accounting (AAA) data. This is control data that is primarily used for granting access, enforcing policy, and measuring usage. The actual network traffic that Diameter controls flows over completely different networks. So if control is what you are after then you should next research which interface(s) you would need for your application. There are many good online resources for that, including RFCs, IETF, 3GPP, and wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Diameter peers use Commands to communicate, where Commands are sets of AVPs (Attribute-Value Pair). Commands and AVPs are defined by the applications that use them.

Why do you want to use Diameter to file transfer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can usee the Diameter protocol for JSON (never tried myself though). But Diameter is a protocol for a specific purpose uses AVPs.

Comment: Concerning the part I deleted:

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to send json or xml data on diameter protocol. Diameter is a strict protocol which works by having well defined command and attribute codes.

Comment: You can use UTF8String avp for  XML or JSON. For sample in 3GPP 32.299 Tariff-XML AVP was specified